# KVM like switch for HP laptops that also shares power, hdmi and usb

Tags: hp-pavilion, kvm-switch, docking-station, hp

Does such a thing/KVM exist where you can connect 2 HP laptops with HDMI outputs to a KVM, but also feed the power via usb C off to both (or even using standard power port)?

Comment: Yes; Type-C KVMs do exist

Comment: Try https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for suggestions, perhps